# Extending PHP function to include more variables

Tags: php

I'm looking extend this PHP function to include more than one variable. This works but only when I've got one product id (8486) against the variable "non_purchasable".

```
function sv_disable_repeat_purchase( $purchasable, $product ) {
    $non_purchasable = 8486;

    $product_id = $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ? $product->variation_id : $product->id;

    if ( $non_purchasable != $product_id ) {
        return $purchasable;
    }

    if ( wc_customer_bought_product( wp_get_current_user()->user_email, get_current_user_id(), $product_id ) ) {
        $purchasable = false;
    }

    if ( $purchasable && $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ) {
        $purchasable = $product->parent->is_purchasable();
    }

    return $purchasable;
}
```

I've tried extending this by creating another variable:

```
$non_purchasable = 8486;
$non_purchasable1 = 8645;
```

**and using two if statements:**

```
if ( $non_purchasable != $product_id ) {
        return $purchasable;
    }
if ( $non_purchasable1 != $product_id ) {
        return $purchasable;
}
```

But the result is that the function no longer works.

I also tried using an array (leaving the rest of the code as is):

```
$non_purchasable=array("8486","8645");
```

But again this didnt work.

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to do here.

Comment: If you want to extend function to pass more variables, then simply redefine function like this :
function sv_disable_repeat_purchase( $purchasable, $product , $another_variable = null) { //whatever code} . Im not sure if this is what you wanted but this will allow you to pass 2 or 3 variables to your function.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. So essentially the above code is designed to lock out product with ID '8486' from a repeat purchase. I'm also wanting to lock out product with ID '8645'. This is currently controlled with the variable "$non_purchasable = 8486;". So my question is how can I extend this variable to include  this additional product ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your array approach is best:

check using:

```
if (!in_array($product_id, $non_purchasable)) {
    return $purchasable;
}
```

Comment: Looks like my array wasnt working becuase I didnt modify the IF statement. This now seems to be working.